# SQL server in ArcGIS 10.2 Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sql-server, oracle-spatial

I am using ArcGIS 10.2, and previously using Oracle spatial as back end.

Now the data providers have shifted to SQL providing core data using FTP which is being staged at SQL server.

We need to import the spatial data from SQl server on daily basis and place in Oracle so it doesn't effect service delivery.

Which would be the best way to add SQL Server connection through ArcGIS desktop?

Comment: Provided you have the connection clients for both databases you should be able to have connections to multiple servers. A tool like Update http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000t000000 would (possibly) be the best way to synchronize - create an arcpy script and run as a scheduled task.

Comment: Just a quick reminder from the [Tour] that "one question per question" works best here.  I recommend that you edit your question (there is an **edit** button beneath it) to leave just the most important issue you want to address first and then research/ask the others separately.

Comment: For sure, as PolyGeo said, after you've looked into this in more depth and have specifics ask all three as separate questions - as well as any others that you will no doubt come across. Esri does some on-line training, if you're new to Esri have a look at that - some of it is free and the rest isn't what I'd consider to be expensive (so long as it's the Boss's pocket it's coming out of). The ArcGis server side of things will be a little harder to get general training on - not as much demand so it tends to be hard to find.